# how to display rich content using jsf component?

Tags: jsf, richfaces, rich-text-editor

I used the rich: editor component to enter rich content and I save it in a database. When I tried to display it in outputText field , rich tags are not interpreted and are displayed as simple text.
So my question is: how can I make the jsf component (or Richfaces) interpret this rich content and display it properly??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `h:outputText` indeed by default escapes [predefined XML/HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) to avoid [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) [attacks](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html). If you want to display user-controlled input unescaped, then just set the `escape` attribute to `false`.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="false" />
```

However, keep potential XSS attacks in mind. If the `rich:editor` isn't already sanitizing user input from XSS, then you can do this with help of among others [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org).