# JSF Encode UTF - 8?

Tags: mysql, jsf, unicode, character-encoding

Now I am working with my friend, he is Vietnamese and he wants to create a website using the Vietnamese Language, but we have a problem with Encode UTF-8.
I wrote a Filter class as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
public class CharsetFilter implements Filter
{
    private String encoding;   

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException
    {
        encoding = config.getInitParameter("requestEncoding");
        if( encoding==null ) encoding="UTF-8";
     }
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain  next)   throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        // Respect the client-specified character encoding
        // (see HTTP specification section 3.4.1)
        if(null == request.getCharacterEncoding())
            request.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
        /** * Set the default response content type and encoding */
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        next.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

config in web.xml:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.mypackage.CharsetFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
                <param-name>requestEncoding</param-name>
                <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CharsetFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

in Server Resources - sun-resources.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE resources PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Application Server 9.0 Resource Definitions //EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-resources_1_3.dtd">
<resources>
  <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="vietweb" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="serverName" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="portNumber" value="3306"/>
        <property name="databaseName" value="vietweb"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value="12345"/>
         <property name="useUnicode" value="true"/>
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF8"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vietweb"/>
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
  </jdbc-connection-pool>
  <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/vietweb" object-type="user" pool-name="mysql_vietweb_rootPool"/>
</resources>
```

in JSF page:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

But it is not being encoded to Vietnamese.
How can we make it encode to Vietnamese?

Problem with save data into DB  ( i use DB is MySQL)
I want/expect this output:

```
chuyển phát nhanh để chuyển tới những cuốn sách
```

but I see this unexpected output:

```
chuy?n phát nhanh ?? chuy?n t?i nh?ng ??u sách
```

Comment: Does the data come from a database?

Comment: Where exactly does it go wrong? With displaying the DB data in JSF page or with saving the JSF form parameters in the DB? How exactly does the unexpected result look like? Update your question to include a copy of both the expected result and the unexpected result (just a word or simple sentence is enough).

Comment: Hi Odelya and BalusC i was edit my question, it come from save Data into DB and it show ?? character

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symptoms indicate that the MySQL DB and/or table is been created as ISO-8859-x instead of UTF-8. Any character which is been outside the ISO-8859-x range will then be stored as `?`. Update the DB and/or table as follows:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
USE dbname;
ALTER TABLE tblname CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

The webapp and DB connection settings are perfectly fine. You would otherwise have seen [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) instead of question marks.

---

That said, the `CharsetFilter` is in essence unnecessary. JSF on Facelets already uses UTF-8 by default. When you're still using legacy JSP instead of Facelets, all you need to do is adding the following line to top of JSP:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

and do only `request.setCharacterEncoding()` in the filter (and do nothing with `response`).

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: Many Thank You Balus, i have small question is how can i display HTML tag inside h:outputText because i save into DB is plain text attach HTML and i want display it on JSF page. Thank You!

Comment: Add `escape="false"`. Keep XSS risks in mind! See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949295/how-to-display-rich-content-using-jsf-component/3949793#3949793) which I posted yesterday.

Comment: Thank you, i also find it too :D

Comment: Sorry for stupid question Balus, Why it return ?? after re-deploy application on server?

Comment: You have to fix the malformed DB content yet.

Comment: i try use ` <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vietweb?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>` in sun-resources.xml but not work

Comment: Hi BalusC i try many way to solved problem Encoding with Glassfish but many way can not solved this problem, do you have ideas for solve it? Thankyou

Comment: You told that the DB contains malformed data. Did you fix it? Update the DB and table to use UTF-8, then delete data and re-insert correct data. Check again if insertion went right.

Comment: Hi BalusC i was check in my DB, it work well, i think my problem in Glassfish, when it deploy Vietnamese can encode but when it re-deploy it occur unexpected character

Comment: You have to be more specific about where the problem occurs.

Comment: In Database i inserted some vietnamese character it Database with WorkBench Management, it good, and deploy good, i found out problem occour with form, if i donn't change any thing in database when it load to form when server deploy, i can see vietnamese character but when i edit some data on form and save it into Database, it occur unexpected character

Comment: Which "unexpected character" exactly? Question marks or mojibake?

Answer (score 0):

I've solve my problem by this statement:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?**useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8**
```

Comment: This is not the cause of OP's concrete problem. The OP was already using this configuration as per `<property name="useUnicode" value="true"/><property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF8"/>` in Glassfish datasource configuration.