# display RTF with JSF

Tags: jsf, rtf, viewer

I need to display a RTF document with JSF - only display. I don't need an RTF Editor like http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/editor.jsf

the

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="false" />
```

doesn't work - its only display the rtf-source

thanks

Thomas

Comment: `<h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="false" />` http://stackoverflow.com/a/3949793/617373

Comment: the <h:outputText value="#{bean.text}" escape="false" /> doesn't work - its only display the rtf-source

Comment: try displaying in "RTF editor in read only mode" without any toolbars/buttons... or try to use iframes with primefaces lightbox http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/lightBox.jsf and http://javaevangelist.blogspot.co.il/2012/09/jsf-21-tip-of-day-using-elements-with.html